# How to display the value of select option on value input text ? (vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My code is like this :

```
<div id="demo">
  <div>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" required>
      <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id">{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>
    {{selected}}
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" :name="elementName" v-model="{{selected}}">
```

See full code here : https://fiddle.jshell.net/stvct9er/1/

After select on combo box, I want to display value of select option on the input text

I try like above code. But it does not work

Please, help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the input inside the demo div because this is the mounted point ,

and with `v-model` just use quotes `<input type="text" v-model="selected">`

https://fiddle.jshell.net/stvct9er/2/